# How to assign a name to a cell in VBA using the first word it contains?

Tags: vba, cell, rename

I would like to automatically and dynamically give a name to each cell once filled. That name should be the first word of cells'content.

Example:

```
A1: CRC02 P2 2019
A2: CRC03 P2 2018
D6: CRC02 P1 2018
```

I would like A1 as well as D6 to be named: CRC02, and A2 to be named CRC03.

I precise there can be empty lines and columns between some cells, because they actually represent a map. The cells I'd like to name aren't in a big sheet, they are just from A1 to AW35.

The Name Manager can't work in my case for two reasons:
- I would need to create them all by hand, naming each cell after their first word.
- Cells content can change and their name should change accordingly.

I've found this macro code on this forum that seem to be a beginning of what I'm looking for but I don't see how to modify it in my case, I guess it asks for several changes. Here, if there is a value in the top row, it sets that value as the name of that cell.

```
Private Sub SortForContactsOutlookImport()
    Dim ThisCell As Object
    Dim NextCell As Object
    Dim RangeName As String

    Set ThisCell = ActiveCell
    Set NextCell = ThisCell.Offset(0, 1)

    Do
        If ThisCell.Value <> "" Then
            RangeName = ThisCell.Value
            ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:=RangeName, RefersTo:=ThisCell
            Set ThisCell = NextCell
            Set NextCell = ThisCell.Offset(0, 1)
        End If
    Loop Until ThisCell.Value = "Web Page"
End Sub
```

Does anyone have an idea?
Thank you so much for your time.

Edit:
I'm sorry I should Indeed have mentioned the main goal.
As I said, all cells of this tab represent a map. One cell is the location of one product in a drawer.
In another tab, I've got the listing of all products with detailed information. Associated with all these details, I'd like to create a hyperlink to the map-containing tab showing where the products are.
I did a test and that works pretty well, showing all the different locations in different drawers at the same time. The only thing is that I should name every single product manually creating named ranges and that would be time-consuming considering the fact that products may leave the drawer and others may arrive. If I have to create named ranges every time one product changes, it wouldn't be worth it.

Comment: Can you use the same name for more than 1 range?  Or do you mean the name is the collection of more than 1 cell?

Comment: To what end?  Are you going to use them to do other things?  Maybe skip the creation of named ranges and use conditions in the end.  To do this, one would need to drop all named ranges and recreate them every time a single cell changes.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this naming? Names must be unique, so you may need to combine A1 and D6 in your example to a single range and name it.

If you could elaborate on the goal it may help find the solution.

Comment: Nathan_Sav, Yes I mean the name is the collection of more than one cell.
Scott Craner, perhaps you have an idea of showing/highlighting products location another way using conditions?

Comment: SnowGroomer, I just edited the main goal.